# Reshape array tuple

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the output of scipy.signal.con2discrete that produces the following tuple:

```
(array([[1., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]), array([[ 0.66      , -0.66      ],
        [ 0.33      , -1.49999601]]), array([0., 1.]), array([0., 0.]), 1)
```

The shape of this object returns (5,)

I would like to get rid of the last '1', and reconstruct the array to have shape (4,3).  That is, the final array that I want should look like this:

```
1., 0., 0.66, -0.66
1., 1., 0.33, -1.5
0., 1., 0., 0.
```

How to do this efficiently in numpy?

Comment: Concatenate the arrays.  May require several steps.

Comment: yes I think this is a good path.  but the challenge is that the arrays are not the same size.  A and B are both (2,2), and C and D are (1,2).  So I can concatenate A and B, and then C and D.  But how to make the last concatenate step?

Comment: I'll try some combination of concatenate and append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [584]: (array([[1., 0.], 
     ...:         [1., 1.]]), array([[ 0.66      , -0.66      ], 
     ...:         [ 0.33      , -1.49999601]]), array([0., 1.]), array([0., 0.])
     ...: , 1)                                                                  
Out[584]: 
(array([[1., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]), array([[ 0.66      , -0.66      ],
        [ 0.33      , -1.49999601]]), array([0., 1.]), array([0., 0.]), 1)
In [585]: x=_                                                                   
In [586]: len(x)                                                                
Out[586]: 5

In [588]: [i.shape for i in x[:4]]                                              
Out[588]: [(2, 2), (2, 2), (2,), (2,)]

In [590]: np.concatenate((x[0],x[1]), axis=1)                                   
Out[590]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.66      , -0.66      ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.33      , -1.49999601]])

In [591]: np.concatenate((x[2],x[3]), axis=0)                                   
Out[591]: array([0., 1., 0., 0.])

In [592]: np.vstack((__, _))                                                    
Out[592]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.66      , -0.66      ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.33      , -1.49999601],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Looks like `block` can be used to do the same thing:

```
In [594]: np.block([[x[0],x[1]],[x[2],x[3]]])                                   
Out[594]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.66      , -0.66      ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.33      , -1.49999601],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: In my case, the starting array is only one possible size.  It looks like I might be able to generalize your approach, which would really be great. This is a great head start and thank you for your response.